# Static left-hand column

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting the left column to be static on my website: bartzjosh.com

I originally set it up as a fluid site, then have been modifying it. Still cleaning it up, so sorry if the code is messy.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have

```
position: absolute
```

set for the sidebar; switch this to

```
position: fixed
```

The `fixed` property establishes the position of the element to the viewport, rather than the document. This causes it to remain frozen in place, regardless of document offset.

Further Reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning